# Indirect inline in Django admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have the following models:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

class Property(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

I would like to create a `TabularInline` displaying every Property connected to a particular `UserProfile` on its Django admin page. The problem here is, of course, that Property does not have a `ForeignKey` directly to `UserProfile`, so I cannot simply write

```
class PropertyTabularInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Property

class UserProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (PropertyTabularInline,)
```

How can I easily do what I want?

Answer (score 2):

You can overwrite the User admin page to display both the `Profile` and the `Property` models.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from myapp.models import *

class ProfileInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Profile

class PropertyInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Property

class UserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    inlines = (ProfileInline, PropertyInline,)

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

You can also remove any unwanted/unused User properties from being displayed (e.g. Groups or Permissions)

more here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model

and here: 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example

Comment: That's not what I want, though -- I want to display the inline on the Profile admin page, not the User admin page.

Answer (score 1):

```
class PropertyTabularInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Property

    def formfield_for_dbfield(self, field, **kwargs):
        if field.name == 'user':
            # implement your method to get userprofile object from request here.
            user_profile = self.get_object(kwargs['request'], UserProfile)
            kwargs["queryset"] = Property.objects.filter(user=user_profile)
        return super(PropertyInLine, self).formfield_for_dbfield(field, **kwargs)
```

once this is done, you can add this inline to user UserProfileAdmin like:

```
class UserProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (PropertyTabularInline,)
```

Haven't tested it, but that should work.

Comment: This won't work for django 1.8 and maybe 1.7 also, it will fail on system check: `<class 'app.admin.PropertyTabularInline'>: (admin.E202) 'app.Property' has no ForeignKey to 'app.UserProfile'.`

Comment: All operations that does perform system check will fail, for example creating new migrations.

Answer (score -1):

It is achievable by making one change in your models.

Instead of creating OneToOne relationship from `UserProfile` to `User`, subclass `User` creating `UserProfile`. Code should look like that:

```
class UserProfile(User):
    # some other fields, no relation to User model

class Property(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

That will result in creating `UserProfile` model that have hidden OneToOne relation to `User` model, it won't duplicate user model.

After doing that change, your code will work. There are some changes under the hood, like `UserProfile` no longer have it's own ID, you can access fields from `User` inside `UserProfile` and it's hard to swap `User` model using `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL` (that will require creating some custom function returning proper type and changing migration by hand) but if this is not a problem for you, it may be good solution.

Comment: This is not an alternative. The point here is that I do *not* want the fields from User to be accessible on UserProfile as I have several UserProfile-like models with OneToOne relationships with User that have different access controls etc.